# BigQuery: "SELECT * would expand to zero columns" with wildcard table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the this query:

```
(SELECT * FROM dataset.my_table) EXCEPT DISTINCT (SELECT * FROM backups.my_table_*)
```

My program keeps adding data to `my_table` and I back up the difference every 3 days to tables called `my_table_{run_date}`. So basically I want to select everything from the big `my_table`, take away everything I've already backed up in the individual backup tables, and then write to a new backup table. I've set up a scheduled query, which tries to run (so I'm fine on the scheduling part), but I keep getting this error on the wildcard part of the query:

```
"SELECT * would expand to zero columns".
```

Backup tables and my_table have the same schema and both contain data.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

I use standard SQL.

Comment: What is the schema of the most recently created table matching the pattern? See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#schema_used_for_query_evaluation

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, thank you, I did identify a table without a schema and removed it. The problem is, every time I run my query (SELECT * FROM dataset.my_table) EXCEPT DISTINCT (SELECT * FROM backups.my_table_*) it creates a new table without a schema and then the next query fails. Why does it create a table without a schema?

Comment: What's the schema of `dataset.my_table`, then? How are you creating the new table, are you using a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement? In the UI, you can click on the destination table after running the query and see the schema.

Comment: I use the old UI to schedule the query. The query string I use it above in the question. The destination table is `my_table_{run_date}`. Schedule is every 72h. Write preference is WRITE_TRUNCATE. So the new table is created from the query result through the scheduled query. I have a lot of scheduled queries and they work great, so I doubt this has to do with scheduling. `dataset.my_table` has 17 columns, strings, timestamp, some integers, none of them repeated fields, really simple schema. If I run a query without wildcard, listing all the tables I have, and using EXCEPT DISTINCT, it works.

Comment: You could [file a bug on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) with whatever detail you can provide